# PFQuery in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm trying to add string objects from Parse to an array using Swift. The array is empty after adding the objects so apparently nothing is being added. What is wrong?

```
var cities = NSMutableArray()

func retrieveCities() {
    let cityQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Locations")
    cityQuery.limit = 1000
    cityQuery.orderByAscending("City")
    cityQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.cities.addObject(object["City"] as! String)
                }
            }

            NSLog("Cities: %@", self.cities)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        } else {       
        }
    }
}
```

This is my objective-c version that works.

```
- (void)retrieveCities {
    self.cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    PFQuery *cityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Locations"];
    [cityQuery setLimit:1000];
    [cityQuery orderByAscending:@"City"];
    [cityQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (NSDictionary *objectDictionary in objects) {
                [self.cities addObject:[objectDictionary objectForKey:@"City"]];
            }

            // Reload the table data and dismiss the loading indicator
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [self.loadingIndicator stopAnimating];
            });
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: Im wondering if the query actually returns anything at all or just a empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid iterating under an assychronous method. Try using `.extend`.

Initialize your array like this:

```
var array: [PFObject] = []
```

And when calling the find method try the following:

```
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    self.array.extend(objects as! [PFObject])
                    println(self.array)
                }else {
                    println(error?.userInfo)
                }
            }
```

Comment: The array is still empty when trying it this way.

Comment: Is the query returning 'objects' with the right data?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the value for the key before you add it as an object...

```
let cityTitle = object.valueForKey("City") as! String
self.cities.addObject(cityTitle)
```

If that doesn't work run a `println` for each object in your `for loop` to make sure that the objects are in fact there.

Comment: It looks like there is nothing to populate the array. Not sure why though.